# Campo Numerico em Web Forms

Tags: javascript, webforms, visual-studio-2015

Pessoal como que eu defino um campo que está em text no webforms para numerico, como exemplo.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="feb" runat="server" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" MaxLength="4" TabIndex="93" Width="90px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

preciso que este campo só receba numeros inteiros

está mask em JavaScript funciona só que ela apaga os valores menores que ela como exemplo

```
jQuery("#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPrinc_ContentPlaceHolder1_feb").mask("9999");
```

se eu digitar 45 no campo e a mascara é "9999" ele não aceita e limpa o campo

Comment: Não tem isso no Web Forms, você pode usar um `RegularExpressionValidator`, uma função `Javascript`, ou até substituir por um `input` normal e setar `type=number`

Comment: eu criei uma mascara só que ela não aceita os digitos menores que a mascara, acabei de atualizar o post, vc pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Pra mim não tem erro algum no seu código, tem certeza que está selecionando o campo certo? Olha esse exemplo que fiz usando a mesma máscara que você colocou no código e funcionou:  https://jsfiddle.net/b3mtxceq/1/

Comment: sim é o campo certo este, o metodo que fez está por input, eu ja tentei fazer a alteração porem da erro no sistema está como asp:TextBox e a mascara em js está do mesmo jeito que coloquei no posto

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tratar impedir que o usuário digite outros caracteres diferentes de números no campo utilizando *KeyDown* com *JQuery* ou validar no *change* do campo.

Se o seu javascript estiver diretamente na página *aspx* utilize *'<%= feb.ClientID %>'* para capturar o *ClientID* do teu campo input. Senão encontre uma forma de levar o nome do campo para a declaração do evento.
Ex:

```
var txtNumber = '<%= feb.ClientID %>';
```

```js
$("#txtNumber1").on('keydown', function (e) {
      return ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) 
      || (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46));
});
        
$("#txtNumber2").on('change', function () {
    $(this).val(ApenasNumeros($(this).val()));
});
        
 function ApenasNumeros(valor) {
      valor = valor.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
      return valor;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtNumber1" type="text" placeholder="keydown" maxlength="4" />
<input id="txtNumber2" type="text" placeholder="change" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: o problema é que meu campo não está como input amigo, está como <asp:TextBox>

Comment: Alterei a resposta com uma dica pra você. No javascript utilizamos o clientID do campo aspx. O clientID nem sempre é o mesmo nome do campo definido na pagina aspx.

Comment: Se der certo, marca como resposta. Dessa forma, sua marcação ajuda outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma pessoal.

```
function somenteNumeros(num) {
    var er = /[^0-9]/;
    er.lastIndex = 0;
    var campo = num;
    if (er.test(campo.value)) {
        campo.value = "";
    }
}

<asp:TextBox ID="feb" runat="server" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" MaxLength="4" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" TabIndex="93" Width="90px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode adicionar o campo `EntryType="inteiro"` no `TextBox`, assim ele só aceita números inteiros.